# Where is the correct type (typescript) for a mapbox layer?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mapbox

It is simplier to explain with an expample. Take a look to this code:

```
const network:any = this.props.network;

    this.map.addLayer({
      id: "route",
      type: "line",
      source: {
        type: "geojson",
        data: network
      },
      layout: {
        "line-join": "round",
        "line-cap": "round"
      },
      paint: {
        "line-color": "red",
        "line-width": 2
      }
    });
```

`this.props.network` Is setted somewhere else, with a code similar to:

```
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/network");
this.props.network = await response.json();
```

This code works as expexted. But I want to set te type correctly for `this.props.network` removing the `any` workaround. `network` is a valid geojson object and VS code show me this hint:

[image]

So I Guess the correct type is: `FeatureCollection<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties>`

But I don't know where are defined that types and what I have to import;

Comment: You do find all types inside the `geojson` package. Therefore `import { FeatureCollection, Geometry, GeoJsonProperties } from "geojson";` should be sufficient. It can be also looked up inside the corresponding `.d.ts` file of `mapbox-gl` here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mapbox-gl/index.d.ts#L13

Comment: That import is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help. If you post it as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The imports you are looking for are located inside the `geojson` package. Therefore the import looks like:

```js
import { FeatureCollection, Geometry, GeoJsonProperties } from "geojson";
```

If looking into the type definition files of `mapbox-gl`, it can be seen, that the `geojson` types are referred here: [Mapbox-GL .d.ts file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mapbox-gl/index.d.ts#L13)